# Переход на новый лист А4

Tags: html, css

Взял готовый шаблон `<page class="A4"></page>` для отображения листа A4 на странице (то есть белый лист, а на остальной странице серый фон, как при открытом PDF в браузере). На эту страницу вывожу данные из базы данных в виде таблицы. Но дело в том, что данных может оказаться настолько много, что на страницу они в итоге не влезут. Есть ли какой-то вариант заставить эту таблицу переходить на новую страницу? Можно конечно вообще убрать оформление и просто выводить все подряд на "бесконечный" белый лист, но хотелось бы с оформлением в виде страничек.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class="A4">
  <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  <div>Много текста...</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.A4 {
  background: white;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 12pt;
}

@media print {
  .page-break {
    display: block;
    page-break-before: always;
  }
  size: A4 portrait;
}

@media print {
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .A4 {
    box-shadow: none;
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
  }
  .noprint {
    display: none;
  }
  .enable-print {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

JavaScript

```
var max_pages = 100;
var page_count = 0;

function snipMe() {
  page_count++;
  if (page_count > max_pages) {
    return;
  }
  var long = $(this)[0].scrollHeight - Math.ceil($(this).innerHeight());
  var children = $(this).children().toArray();
  var removed = [];
  while (long > 0 && children.length > 0) {
    var child = children.pop();
    $(child).detach();
    removed.unshift(child);
    long = $(this)[0].scrollHeight - Math.ceil($(this).innerHeight());
  }
  if (removed.length > 0) {
    var a4 = $('<div class="A4"></div>');
    a4.append(removed);
    $(this).after(a4);
    snipMe.call(a4[0]);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.A4').each(function() {
    snipMe.call(this);
  });
});
```

Comment: А если у меня эти данные в таблице находятся и таблица становится больше размера А4, можно ли как-то осуществить и перенос части строк таблицы? А то сейчас получается, что она вся переносится на новый лист, а если она  больше размера А4, то вообще багается.

Comment: Возможно этот код сможет решить вашу проблему: http://jsfiddle.net/ax8fd0bs/